# Почему результат фильтра галереи не появляется на нужной странице?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, плагин, filter

Есть сайт на wordpress со страницей с видеогалереей. Для фильтрации по ней используется плагин WordPress [Meta Data Filter & Taxonomies Filter - MDTF](http://wp-filter.com/) в виджете в сайдбаре. Фильтрует все хорошо, единственное открывает результирующую страницу не в том виде (шаблоне), который мне нужен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делаю все согласно рекомендациям автора [в видео](https://youtu.be/Cd7RNyLY4Sc?t=48m49s), создаю собственный шаблон, указываю его в настройках здесь - не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробую задать, чтобы вывод приходился на туже страницу через **self** - в таком случае на странице остаюсь, но самой фильтрации не происходит...
пытаюсь хакнуть фильтр виджета для вывода фильтра согласно [рекомендациям](http://wp-filter.com/howto/get-search-arguments-action-page-hack-portfolio-shortcode/)

```
<?php 
if(class_exists('MetaDataFilter') AND MetaDataFilter::is_page_mdf_data()){    
   $_REQUEST['mdf_do_not_render_shortcode_tpl'] = true;
   $_REQUEST['mdf_get_query_args_only'] = true;
   do_shortcode('[meta_data_filter_results]');
   $args = $_REQUEST['meta_data_filter_args'];
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
   $_REQUEST['meta_data_filter_found_posts']=$wp_query->found_posts;
}
?>
```

и снова не выходит. как можно устранить проблему?
сам шаблон страницы:

```
<?php
/**
 * The left sidebar widget area.
 *
 * @package ThemeGrill
 * @subpackage ColorMag
 * @since ColorMag 1.0
 */
?>

<div id="secondary">
  <?php do_action( 'colormag_before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php
      if( is_page_template( 'page-templates/contact.php' ) ) {
        $sidebar = 'colormag_contact_page_sidebar';
      }
      else {
        $sidebar = 'colormag_left_sidebar';
      }
    ?>

    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar ) ) :
         if ( $sidebar == 'colormag_contact_page_sidebar' ) {
            $sidebar_display = __('Contact Page', 'colormag');
         } else {
            $sidebar_display = __('Left', 'colormag');
         }
         the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text',
            array(
               'title'  => __( 'Example Widget', 'colormag' ),
               'text'   => sprintf( __( 'This is an example widget to show how the %s Sidebar looks by default. You can add custom widgets from the %swidgets screen%s in the admin. If custom widgets are added then this will be replaced by those widgets.', 'colormag' ), $sidebar_display, current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ? '<a href="' . admin_url( 'widgets.php' ) . '">' : '', current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ? '</a>' : '' ),
               'filter' => true,
            ),
            array(
               'before_widget' => '<aside class="widget widget_text clearfix">',
               'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
               'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title"><span>',
               'after_title'   => '</span></h3>'
            )
         );
      endif; ?>
<?php 
if(class_exists('MetaDataFilter') AND MetaDataFilter::is_page_mdf_data()){    
   $_REQUEST['mdf_do_not_render_shortcode_tpl'] = true;
   $_REQUEST['mdf_get_query_args_only'] = true;
   do_shortcode('[meta_data_filter_results]');
   $args = $_REQUEST['meta_data_filter_args'];
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
   $_REQUEST['meta_data_filter_found_posts']=$wp_query->found_posts;
}
?>
  <?php do_action( 'colormag_after_sidebar' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: И что у Вас написано в настройках Results output page link и Results output template?

Comment: @labris пробовал различные комбинации: `'self',''` `'self','self'` `'self','self'` `'http://domen.com/en/mdtf-results-page/','search-template'` и т.п. - не помогает

Comment: Там должна быть http ссылка на страницу на вашем сайте, которую создает плагин при установке, типа того.
Тут подробно все описано - http://wp-filter.com/step-by-step-na-russkom/

Comment: @labris спасибо. Я понял в чем у меня затык - я фильтрую внутри шорткода, а вывод в шаблоне идет как простой контент